# Google Docs script, return text value in the middle of specified text

Tags: scripting, expression, documentation, google-docs

[current result][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8AGa.png

- The problem is that they all apply to the same line
- I want to get the values individually from the same line

1. Rule

   ▶random text◁

   →  Change only values between ▶ and ◁
2. Script currently in use

```
 
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var foundElement = body.findText('▶([^\S]+)◁');
 
while (foundElement != null) {
   // Get the text object from the element
   var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
 
   // Where in the element is the found text?
   var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
   var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
 
   // Set Bold
   foundText.setBold(start, end, true);
   // Change the Foreground color
   foundText.setForegroundColor(start, end, "#ff326d");
 
   // Find the next match
   foundElement = body.findText('▶([^\S]+)◁', foundElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Some regular expressions are not fully supported

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern) `A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.`

I'd recommend to open a feature request on Google Issue Tracker as recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features)

Comment: ('▶([^\S]+)◁') -> ('▶([^\S]+?)◁')    '?' success by adding      processing completed :)